# Is it necessary to sanitize data being passed into the hash_hmac in php?

Tags: php, hmac

I have a page that takes in arguments that could possibly be changed by a malicious user. I am checking to make sure that the contents have not been unexpectedly changed by using HMAC. In php, there is a function called hash_hmac. Do I need to sanitize the input into this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, any combination of bytes you might send into hash_hmac in the $data parameter will be correctly processed by the function, so no sanitation is needed at that point in your script. However, you'll probably still need to do sanitation *at some point* in your script, but by checking the mac up front, you'll prevent all those wasted CPU cycles sanitizing data that was actually just a forged request.